# Clearing the scanner to print out empty string

Tags: java, string, constructor, java.util.scanner

I have a tag maker class that needs to print out two tags. one needs to print out the user input, and then I have to clear the scanner buffer and print out an empty tag right afterwards. as of now, I get two tags that print the original user input.

```
    package stupidtag;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StupidTag {

String first; 
String last;
String org;
String s;

Scanner scanMe = new Scanner(System.in);


public void setFirst(String first){
this.first = first; 
}

public void setLast(String last){
this.last = last;
}

public void setOrganization(String org){
this.org = org;
}


    void tagMaker() {
              s    = ("———————NAME TAG———————" + "\n" + "Name: " +
                    last + ", " + first + "\n" + "Organization: " + org +
                    "\n"+ "---------------------"); 

     if((first.equals(first)) || (last.equals(last)) || (org.equals(org)))
{
        System.out.println(s);

}
     else{

            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
            scanMe.nextLine(); // -->important
            System.out.println();
}
        scanMe.reset();
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    }
}
```

and here's the tester:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;


public class stupidTagTester {
     public static void main(String args[]){


   Scanner scanMe = new Scanner( System.in );


    StupidTag tag = new StupidTag();


     System.out.print("This program will print out a name tag");
     System.out.println("for each delegate.");
     System.out.println("Please enter first name:");
     tag.first = scanMe.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Please enter last name:");
     tag.last = scanMe.next();
     System.out.println("Please enter organization or affilation:");
     tag.org = scanMe.next();
     tag.tagMaker();
   }

}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

You are only resetting the scanner.  Once you do that, add some code that will clear the fields added as well.

Example:

```
...
    scanMe.reset();
    first = "";
    last = "";
    org = "";
    System.out.println(s);
}
```